# How to set a shortcut key for choosing current word in IDEA2019?

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

Generally, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> is the shortcut for **choosing current word** in JetBrains IDEA.
But in latest IDEA Community version, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> is uesd for **closing current tab/window**.

How to set a shortcut key for choosing current word in IDEA2019?

I know I can do it in the Keymap setting, but I can't find the item for 'choosing current word'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the shortcut for selecting the word you must change the `Extend Selection` setting in ["Editor Actions"](https://prnt.sc/rre20h) section.